# Vue js v-for not working when array passed through props

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, laravel-5

I don't get it for some reason when i pass array through props `v-for` wont work and only difference i can see from directly writing data is that one passed from props don't have spaces in between.

I am using laravel and through blade im passing data to vue, data is array of all photos with informations. But that data won't list through all photos and display div's.

Let me show you my code:

This is what i have in blade template:

```
<picture-upload
    :input_value="'{{ json_encode($profilephotos) }}'"
    :bind_user="'{{ $profile->id }}'"
    :input_name="'profilephoto'"
    :post_url="'{{ route('photouploads') }}'"
    :type="'profilephoto'"
></picture-upload>
```

I don't think that `json_encode` make difference in this case but i tried it any way.

And this is what i have in my `photos.vue` file

```
props: ['input_name', 'post_url', 'bind_user', 'type', 'input_value'],
    data() {
        return {
            files: [],
            uploads: this.input_value,
            items: [
              {"id":110,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"5.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"3f49191095d302fb7e66ce037dd5efa111287e8230964ad8a3170687ca4336a1","size":192445,"created_at":"2019-04-23 16:04:01","updated_at":"2019-04-23 16:04:01"},
              {"id":111,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"4.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"0bd693c2cd1ab5ec2c7223fc6a92356ab68c52e8cc0b7d5d5aa5b4a230cf015b","size":193223,"created_at":"2019-04-23 21:58:52","updated_at":"2019-04-23 21:58:52"},
              {"id":112,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"5.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"0bd693c2cd1ab5ec2c7223fc6a92356ab68c52e8cc0b7d5d5aa5b4a230cf015b","size":192445,"created_at":"2019-04-23 21:58:52","updated_at":"2019-04-23 21:58:52"},
              {"id":113,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"4.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"ffe6f95d10c5249390fcea140fe15a1fb57f5d29626a947e4a999db50f3ea295","size":193223,"created_at":"2019-04-23 22:00:10","updated_at":"2019-04-23 22:00:10"},
              {"id":114,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"4.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"75a00a901f1a01a0267d44bebc8574efa9eb7a7edfd395e29dabb289efb353ac","size":193223,"created_at":"2019-04-23 22:05:32","updated_at":"2019-04-23 22:05:32"}
            ]
        }
    },
```

So `input_value` is what is passed from blade template, and `items` is what i added manually for testing, `items` is exactly the same as what i see when i output data in frontend.

Here is what i have in `.vue` `<template>` section

```
{{ items }}

<li v-for="item in items">
   {{ item.type }}
</li>

{{ uploads }}

<div v-for="upload in uploads">
  {{ upload.type }}
</div>
```

So `items` should output complete array and `v-for` should filter and output foreach item in that array, which should go the same for `uploads` but problem is `uploads` not working.

This is what i actually get in frontent

For `{{ items }}`

```
[ { "id": 110, "user_id": 28, "type": "profilephoto", "name": "5.jpg", "mime": "image/jpeg", "extension": "jpg", "path": "3f49191095d302fb7e66ce037dd5efa111287e8230964ad8a3170687ca4336a1", "size": 192445, "created_at": "2019-04-23 16:04:01", "updated_at": "2019-04-23 16:04:01" }, { "id": 111, "user_id": 28, "type": "profilephoto", "name": "4.jpg", "mime": "image/jpeg", "extension": "jpg", "path": "0bd693c2cd1ab5ec2c7223fc6a92356ab68c52e8cc0b7d5d5aa5b4a230cf015b", "size": 193223, "created_at": "2019-04-23 21:58:52", "updated_at": "2019-04-23 21:58:52" }, { "id": 112, "user_id": 28, "type": "profilephoto", "name": "5.jpg", "mime": "image/jpeg", "extension": "jpg", "path": "0bd693c2cd1ab5ec2c7223fc6a92356ab68c52e8cc0b7d5d5aa5b4a230cf015b", "size": 192445, "created_at": "2019-04-23 21:58:52", "updated_at": "2019-04-23 21:58:52" }, { "id": 113, "user_id": 28, "type": "profilephoto", "name": "4.jpg", "mime": "image/jpeg", "extension": "jpg", "path": "ffe6f95d10c5249390fcea140fe15a1fb57f5d29626a947e4a999db50f3ea295", "size": 193223, "created_at": "2019-04-23 22:00:10", "updated_at": "2019-04-23 22:00:10" }, { "id": 114, "user_id": 28, "type": "profilephoto", "name": "4.jpg", "mime": "image/jpeg", "extension": "jpg", "path": "75a00a901f1a01a0267d44bebc8574efa9eb7a7edfd395e29dabb289efb353ac", "size": 193223, "created_at": "2019-04-23 22:05:32", "updated_at": "2019-04-23 22:05:32" } ]
```

And there `v-for="item in items"` logic works, if i do

```
<li v-for="item in items">
   {{ item.type }}
</li>
```

I will get list of `item.type`

The problem happens if i do exactly the same with `uploads` something is not working.

If i test output of `{{ uploads }}` i will get exactly same array as with `items` except there are spaces between things in array.

This is output of `{{ uploads }}`

```
[{"id":110,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"5.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"3f49191095d302fb7e66ce037dd5efa111287e8230964ad8a3170687ca4336a1","size":192445,"created_at":"2019-04-23 16:04:01","updated_at":"2019-04-23 16:04:01"},{"id":111,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"4.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"0bd693c2cd1ab5ec2c7223fc6a92356ab68c52e8cc0b7d5d5aa5b4a230cf015b","size":193223,"created_at":"2019-04-23 21:58:52","updated_at":"2019-04-23 21:58:52"},{"id":112,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"5.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"0bd693c2cd1ab5ec2c7223fc6a92356ab68c52e8cc0b7d5d5aa5b4a230cf015b","size":192445,"created_at":"2019-04-23 21:58:52","updated_at":"2019-04-23 21:58:52"},{"id":113,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"4.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"ffe6f95d10c5249390fcea140fe15a1fb57f5d29626a947e4a999db50f3ea295","size":193223,"created_at":"2019-04-23 22:00:10","updated_at":"2019-04-23 22:00:10"},{"id":114,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"4.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"75a00a901f1a01a0267d44bebc8574efa9eb7a7edfd395e29dabb289efb353ac","size":193223,"created_at":"2019-04-23 22:05:32","updated_at":"2019-04-23 22:05:32"},{"id":115,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"4.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"c0db13b85c255a30b8466ca5778cad05d06f20f2cf12a3db46e9b6a7d182fdd8","size":193223,"created_at":"2019-04-23 22:14:37","updated_at":"2019-04-23 22:14:37"},{"id":116,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"4.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"3591cedc64c8f3638d71643291ce2e37d697dbcdfe08c715254d94237b93b1a1","size":193223,"created_at":"2019-04-23 22:21:37","updated_at":"2019-04-23 22:21:37"}]
```

And if i try to do

```
<div v-for="upload in uploads">
  {{ upload.type }}
</div>
```

I get whole bunch of empty div's with not `upload.type` output. Plus i have like 20 images in total, i get like 200 empty div's.

This confuses me alot as why it is happening like this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are JSON encoding the variable thus you are passing a `string`. This is in essence correct, but you also might want to change

`:input_value="'{{ json_encode($profilephotos) }}'"`

to

`:input_value="{{ json_encode($profilephotos) }}"`

Comment: That's it, omg something so simple it took me 2 hours i couldn't figure out. It works, but why is difference if i use `'` or not ?

Comment: `json_encode` returns a `string` (in PHP terms) but it is directly parsable as javascript. In javascript it either represents array/number/string/object, so you could do `let myvar = {{ json_encode($profilephotos) }}` (echoing the blade directive into a javascript snippet). This results in `myvar` being an array/number/string/object, while if you put quotes around it it becomes a string.